# How can I display each days events?

Tags: coldfusion

I have an events page where I need to display the events for each day. I've gotten it to this point, so I'm making progress.

The database has 3 tables: fairdays, eventtypes, events

- fairdays: id, fairdaydate (datetime), daycolor, description
- eventtypes: id, eventtype  <-- This table is for the input select in the "add event form"
- events: id, eventname, eventtype, eventday (datetime), eventtime (datetime)

My intent is to display the day with the description, then under that is the event types, then under each of those is the corresponding events.

I haven't worked out how to display the event type sub heading, then the individual events under each of those, but here's my code so far. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
<cfquery datasource="fairscheduledb" name="getfairdays">
    select * from fairdays
</cfquery>

<cfquery datasource="fairscheduledb" name="getfairevents">
    select * from events ev
    inner join fairdays fd on fd.fairdaydate = ev.eventday
    where ev.eventday = fd.fairdaydate
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="getfairdays">

<cfoutput>
    <div class="schedulebox">
        <div class="schedulehead" style="color: ###getfairdays.daycolor#;">#dateformat(getfairdays.fairdaydate,"dddd, mmmm dd")#</div>
        <div class="schedulesubhead" style="color: ##ffffff; background: ###getfairdays.daycolor#;">#getfairdays.description#</div>
        <cfoutput query="getfairevents">
            <div class="scheduleitem" style="float: left; width: 75px; text-align: right;">#LCase(TimeFormat(getfairevents.eventtime,"h:mmtt"))#</div>
            <div class="scheduleitem" style="float: left; width: 550px;">#getfairevents.eventname#</div><br/>
        </cfoutput>
    </div>
</cfoutput>

</cfloop>
```

Here's what the list of days and events should look like:

```
<div class="schedulebox">

    <div class="schedulehead" style="color: #4CC417;">Friday, February 22</div>
    <div class="schedulesubhead" style="color: #ffffff; background: #4CC417;">Opening Ceremony 4:30pm at Gate<br/>5:00 - 6:00pm - Free Admission &amp; Free Rides</div>
    <div class="scheduleitemtitle" style="color: #4CC417;">Strolling Acts</div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">5:30pm - Scotts Magic Show</div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">6:30pm - Rock-It the Robot</div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">7:30pm - Scotts Magic Show</div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">8:30pm - Rock-It the Robot</div>
    <div class="scheduleitemtitle" style="color: #4CC417;">Acts</div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">5:30pm - Sea Lion Show</div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">6:00pm - Alligator Wrestling</div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">6:30pm - Petting Zoo Presentation </div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">8:00pm - Alligator Wrestling</div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">8:30pm - Petting Zoo Presentation </div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">9:00pm - Sea Lion Show</div>
        <div class="scheduleitemtitle" style="color: #4CC417;">Stage Acts</div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">7:00pm - Youth Royalty</div>
    <div class="scheduleitemtitle" style="color: #4CC417;">Livestock Program</div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">6:00pm - Beef Breeding Screening</div>
        <div class="scheduleitem">7:00pm - Horse Judging Competition</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Small note, do not use `select *`. Select the columns you need by name. Also, you can skip the `where` clause. It is redundant. Those columns were already matched in the `join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is too long for comments ...)

To expand on [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21483596/104223), he is suggesting a more efficient way of producing that output by using JOIN's and [cfoutput's group feature](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff6.html) (emphasis is mine):

> ... Eliminates adjacent duplicate rows **when data is sorted**. Use if you
>   retrieved a record set ordered on one or more a query columns. For
>   example, if a record set is ordered on "Customer_ID" in the cfquery
>   tag, you can group the output on "Customer_ID."

For your JOIN's you will need to include all three tables to grab all of the columns you need. I cannot test it right now, but something along these lines. (Notice the results are sorted the same way you wish to display them ie by event date, type and time)

```
SELECT  ev.eventDay, t.EventType, ev.EventTime
FROM    fairdays fd 
          INNER JOIN events ev ON ev.eventDay = fd.fairdaydate
          INNER JOIN eventType t ON t.ID = ev.EventType

ORDER BY ev.eventDay, t.EventType, e.EventTime
```

Once you have the sorted results, use "group" generate the desired results. Be sure to `group` by the same columns, *in the same order*, as the sql query. Otherwise, it will not work correctly.

```
<cfoutput query="yourQuery" group="EventDay">    
    <!--- display event dates --->     
     #EventDay# <hr/>    
    <!--- event types for current date --->
    <cfoutput group="EventType">
        #EventType#<br/>
        <!--- individual events --->
        <cfoutput>
            #EventTime# <br/>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfoutput> 
</cfoutput>
```

**Update from comments:**

As discussed in the comments, if you want to retrieve all fairdays (even ones without a matching event) use [outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) instead of inner joins.

```
SELECT  fd.fairDayDate, t.ID, ev.EventType, ev.EventTime
FROM    fairdays fd 
          INNER JOIN events ev ON ev.eventDay = fd.fairDayDate
          INNER JOIN eventType t ON t.ID = ev.EventType

ORDER BY fd.fairDayDate, t.ID, e.EventTime
```

Again, since the cfoutput "group" feature requires sorted query data to work properly, if you change the ORDER BY clause, be sure to update the "group" columns to match your `ORDER BY` clause. ie Group by `fairDayDate` first, then event `ID`:

```
<cfoutput query="yourQuery" group="fairDayDate">    
    <!--- display event dates --->     
     #fairDayDate# <hr/>    
    <!--- event types for current date --->
    <cfoutput group="ID">
        #EventType#<br/>
        <!--- individual events --->
        <cfoutput>
            #EventTime# <br/>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfoutput> 
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Now I understand. I think so, anyway. I thought when I did the join, that I was ONLY getting the column I requested in the join. So, you're saying all the columns are available to me now that I have done the join? If that's true, I'm liking this join thing.

Comment: Basically, yes. The `join` clause determines how to match up the records between the various tables. The `select` list determines what columns the query object contains.

Comment: With this I get an error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Strolling Acts' to data type int."...

"Scolling Acts" is an event type. There are several.

Comment: Nevermind. That was an easy fix. Now, how do I award the answer to more than one person?

Comment: You can only pick one "answer", but you can vote up any post(s) you found helpful.

Comment: One more question, then I'm out of here. How do I get it to display a day if that day does not have any events. For example, the first day is a "Sneak Peek" day, so all it needs to display is fairdaydate and description from the fairdays table.

Comment: Use [outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) instead of `inner join`s.

Comment: That almost worked. However, all it's showing me for the "Sneak Peek" is the description. The fairdaydate is blank. What did I miss?

Comment: Oh, right. You will also need to SELECT the date column from `fairdays` instead of `events`, because the event record might be null due to the outer join. ie Use `SELECT fd.FairDayDate, ....`

Comment: That worked great. I used left outer, and got what I was looking for. Now, I have one event where the eventtime was unintentionally set for 8:45am and was being displayed at the top of the list of events (as expected), so I changed it to 8:45pm. Once I did that it's now displaying at the bottom of the list of events under later times. In other words, that one event is out of order.

Comment: Well 8:45am is not a datetime value, it is a string. But this is a different question. You should open a new thread, so others with the same issue will be able to find it without digging through comments. Be sure to include the column data type, sample values, etcetera.

Answer (score 4):

First, you don't need the first query.

Next, add

```
order by eventday
```

to query getfairevents.  That will enable you to do this:

```
<cfoutput query="getfairevents" group = "eventday">
    #eventday#
    <cfoutput>
        output other stuff here (individual events and times)
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: The first query gives me the day and description of that day. I have to display that first. Then, beneath that, the event types, then under each event type, the events for that day and event type.

Comment: (Edit) Dan is describing how you can achieve that result (more efficiently) using a `join` and cfoutput's "group" feature. You may need to tweak it, but give it a try to better understand the technique.

Comment: But your 2nd query is using the same table.