# Odd placement of event in schedule

Tags: coldfusion

I have a page that shows a schedule of events over a period of time. Thanks to Leigh on this site, I was able to get it working the way I wanted, except for one small issue. One of the events is placed at the bottom of one of the lists that is sorted by the datetime column "eventtime". I'm baffled.

Here's my code:

```
   <cfquery datasource="fairscheduledb" name="getfairevents">
    SELECT  fd.FairDayDate, fd.daycolor, fd.description, ev.eventname, ev.eventday, t.eventtype, ev.eventtime
    FROM    fairdays fd
          LEFT OUTER JOIN events ev ON ev.eventday = fd.fairdaydate
          LEFT OUTER JOIN eventtypes t ON t.eventtype = ev.eventtype
    ORDER BY fd.fairDaydate, t.id, ev.eventtime
   </cfquery>

<cfoutput query="getfairevents" group="eventday">
    <div class="schedulebox">
        <!--- display event dates --->
        <div class="schedulehead" style="clear: both; color: ###daycolor#;">#dateformat(fairdaydate,"dddd, mmmm dd")#</div>
        <div class="schedulesubhead" style="clear: both; color: ##ffffff; background: ###daycolor#;">#description#</div>
        <!--- event types for current date --->
        <cfoutput group="eventtype">
            <div class="scheduleitemtitle" style="clear: both; width: 700px; color: ###daycolor#;">#eventtype#</div>
            <!--- individual events --->
            <cfoutput>
                <div class="scheduleitem" style="float: left; width: 75px; text-align: right;"><strong>#LCase(TimeFormat(eventtime,"h:mmtt"))#</strong></div>
                <div class="scheduleitem" style="float: left; width: 550px;"> #eventname#</div><br/>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfoutput>
    </div>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Since you are doing left outer joins, its possible that t.id is null (so it gets ordered out of sync with the other eventtimes)... and therefore the eventtype is null and the div without content could not show, and could look like it is at the bottom of the list, but its really just missing its header. Could this be it?

Comment: Interesting thought. As soon as I get back to the office I'll have a look.

Comment: Ok. I had a look at the generated html, and there is nothing missing. Got any other ideas?

Comment: It looks right, unless there was some null values interfering. 
Thats why I thought maybe the scheduleitemtitle div was in the html, but not visible looking at the page... therefore looking like it was ordered wrong.

Comment: Can you post a dump of the raw query? It would be easier to pinpoint the problem if we could see the raw values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the problem, and it was a stupid one for me to miss. When I changed that specific entry yesterday, and typed in the correct time, it "auto inserted" the current date. In other words, I typed "8:45pm", and hit enter, and MSSQL automatically converts it to "2014-01-31 19:45:00.000", because yesterday was 01-31-2014. When the data was originally entered, it was 01-23-2014, so all of the entries reflected that date. Because the data type I used for that column was datetime.

I solved the problem by changing the data type to time(7), and viola, all is well. I feel stupid, now.

Thanks to everyone that tried to help with this.

Comment: You should either mark this as the answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're grouping your output on eventday and eventtype.  You need to add those two columns to your ORDER BY, otherwise you can get unpredictably-ordered results.

```
ORDER BY fd.fairDaydate, t.id, ev.eventday, ev.eventtime, ev.eventtype
```

Comment: Though the time problem was caused by something else, this raises a good point. Though you do not need to change the ORDER BY, only the cfoutput "group" columns. @JoeNobody - Since [we changed your sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21484672/104223), just be sure your groups match the original ORDER BY clause.  In other words, since you are now ordering by "fairDayDate" instead of "eventDate", you need to group by it first `<cfoutput group="fairDayDate">`, then the event ie `<cfoutput group="id">`. That will ensure the correct results.